# C# store app, send parameters on Basic page back button

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I made a C# Store app. I send parameters to a page and read them, this all works fine. I send the parameters to other pages like this:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetailPage), UniqueID); //(works)
```

I make use of the basic pages (because it has a default backbutton and title. Now i want to send the parameter that i sended to the ItemDetailPage (like i did in above example) back in the page i am currently on, perhaps in the back button?

does anyone has a solution how i can save/ retreive de value when i return to this current page?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Store the value in a public static property.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to perform this: 
1) Store the value in IsolatedStorageSettings object which is define in app.xaml.cs and store value in this and retrive in your desired pages.
Example :

```
 public IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
  store value like this : 
  (App.Current as App).settings.Add("sampledata", txtsomething.Text);  
  for retrive : 
  (string)(App.Current as App).settings["sampledata"];
  and whenever you want to update the data just remove the value inside this and then add     again.
```

2) decalre variable in app.xaml.cs and access it anywhere.